# Maria DB Can't drop table with ENGINE=CONNECT without root

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector, mariadb-connect-engine

As in topic I can create and drop table in Maria DB as root, but I can't drop table as normal user. It happens only when tabel engine is connect.

As root:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_database.* To 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR user@localhost;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*EE22D94139EAEE5486C30FBC352B12340EEF82F5' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Login from root account as normal user:

```
# mysql -u user -p
Enter password: 

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 20120
Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [test_database]> CREATE TABLE example (id INT, data VARCHAR(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.61 sec)

MariaDB [test_database]> DROP TABLE example;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test_database]> CREATE TABLE odbc_test ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=ODBC tabname='sample_table' CONNECTION='DSN=mssql_test;UID=test_user;PWD=password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test_database]> DROP TABLE odbc_test;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
MariaDB [test_database]> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*EE22D94139EAEE5486C30FBC352B12340EEF82F5' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test_database]> select current_user;
+-----------------+
| current_user    |
+-----------------+
| user@localhost |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

What kind of privileges does user have to drop table with engine=connect?

1. Update1. Checking with csv file like in this link: 
   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-csv-and-fmt-table-types/

It works as root, but as user with all priviliges I can't even create table.

```
MariaDB [test_database]> create table people (name char(12) not null,   birth date not null date_format='DD/MM/YY',   children smallint(2) not null) engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='test.csv' header=1 sep_char=';' quoted=1;

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

**Problem solved**

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

Comment: Just to try, you have tried to CREATE and DROP a test table with another TABLE_TYPE, for example, CSV?

Comment: @wchiquito I updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solved my problem :-)

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
```